# How to prove set of all two argument functions cannot be countable

Tags: computability, countable

We can prove that set of all one argument functions cannot be countable using the cantor's diagonal. 
for example

```
     1    2    3    4    5    6    7 ......

f1   10   12   23   1    3    12   3 ......    
f2   15    6    7   8    9    11   4 ...... 
f3   14    2    4   3    3     4   5 ...... 
f4   12    2    3   5    1    20   56 .....   
.
.
.
```

for all functions f1  to fn we can pass all the arguments and 1 to n for some n. then by taking the diagonal values and add 1 to diagonal values and we can prove that we can't count all the one argument functions.(since change the diagonal values will produce a row unique which haven't listed)

Wonder is there a particular method to count two argument functions also??..

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found an answer. I'm writing the answer in case anyone is interested.

we can prove than all the pairs of positive integers can be countable. see below

```
(1,1) (1,2) (1,3) (1,4) (1,5) (1,6).....
(2,1) (2,2) (2,3) (2,4) (2,5) (2,6).....
(3,1) (3,2) (3,3) (3,4) (3,5) (3,6).....
(4,1) (4,2) (4,3) (4,4) (4,5) (4,6).....
 .
 .
 .
```

so from the cantor's zig zag we can prove that they can be countable.. see page 8 on this book http://www.scribd.com/doc/51068193/3/Enumerable-Sets

```
(1,1) (1,2) (2,1) (1,3) (2,2) (3,1) ....
```

so we can write our problem as below.

```
    (1,1)   (1,2)   (2,1)   (1,3)   (2,2)   (3,1)

f1   10      12       23       1      3       12    ......    
f2   15       6        7       8      9       11    ...... 
f3   14       2        4       3      3        4    ...... 
f4   12       2        3       5      1       20    ......   
.
.
.
```

Now by the knowledge of cantor's diagonal.. we can argue that all the two argument functions can't be countable.

Comment: This is unnecessarily complex. You have a trivial injection of one argument functions into two arguments functions. If the latter was countable the former would be too.

Answer (score 0):

*Wonder is there a particular method to count two argument functions also??..*

You mean *Wonder is there a particular method to count two argument functions?* ("also" would imply that one exists for one-argument functions).

If a subset of a non-countable set is always also noncountable then you could just use the subset of the set of all two-argument functions where you fix the second parameter to a constant (making it essentially equal to a one-argument-function). However I doubt that this assumption is true.

I think you left out some important prerequisites about the diagram (how the fn are constructed as they are not chosen arbitrarily). Maybe examining them will lead you to the clue? I guess this is a homework question? Is it allowed on stackoverflow to post homework questions and in your university to have them let solved by someone else?

Comment: This isn't any home work question.I asked it for just curiosity. In the book "George S. Boolos_ John P. Burgess_ Richard C. Jeffrey - Computability and Logic". They have explained that all sets of positive integers can't be countable using the cantor's diagonal. That's a good point you've made that using the second argument as a constant value..